# Access ASP.NET website deployed on IIS Windows Server from outside network

Tags: windows-server-2008, firewall, deployment, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET website deployed on IIS in Windows Server. It works fine in LAN. All PC in the network can access the website using the IP of server and port. Now I want to be able to access the website from outside network. How can I do that? Please help me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need quite some "facilities" and Know-how to make this work safe and reliable from your own LAN.

I'd suggest you do a google search for something like "web hosting explained" and see by yourself what options are available.

Once you have acquired more knowledge on this topic and know exactly what you want to do, we'll be happy to help you on specific problems you might be facing while setting up whatever you want to.